# What define can I use in a portable library to tell if the compiler is Microsoft's?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

I have a portable library that in one place needs to do X if compiled under Visual Studio or just with Microsoft's C/C++ compiler, and Y otherwise. What `#define` should I look for?

Comment: you can find lots defines in boost library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_MSC_VER` is what you're looking for regarding MSVC compilers and their versions

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  .. MSVC compiler
#endif
```

and you can also use that to specialize your code across MSVC versions

```
#if _MSC_VER > 1700
  .. MSVC compiler is greater than 11 (2012)
#endif
```

Another list of compiler macros can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

Answer (score 6):

A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=msvc+predefined+macros) leads to [predefined macros on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) which lists all macros predefined by MSVC. Out of these, `_MSC_VER` is likely the best candidate.

Comment: I pretty much agree that it is the preferred candidate, but the page you cite doesn't seem to say anything about that.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks, was writing rather quickly. Re-worded.